# Call method from another class with parameters

Tags: objective-c, parameters, methods, iphone

I have a little problem with calling a method from another class with parameters.
I am programming since a few weeks objC.

My aim is to load in another class a method, called:

```
- (void) openTheCamera:(UIImagePickerController*) reader 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info {
```

I am calling a method without parameters this way:

```
[theOtherClassname theOtherMethod];
```

But how can I call it with parameters?
I have tried:

```
[theOtherClassname openTheCamera:(UIImagePickerController*) reader 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info];
```

I think that's wrong. How can I do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[theOtherClassname openTheCamera:(UIImagePickerController*) reader 
didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info];
```

should work as expected, but the type specifiers are unnecessary and can be even harmful, because you [type-cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) `reader` to `UIImagePickerController *` and `info` to `NSDictionary *`. This is bad, because the compiler won't notify you if your input parameters are of a type that your method does not expect.

You can simply do:

```
[theOtherClassname openTheCamera:reader didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:info];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use easily protocols:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html

Search in this site. you could able to find similar questions...